# How to genernate a ECIES function in Java?

Tags: java, ruby, openssl, ecdsa, ecies

I am busy in a decryption of encrypted data work.

Another business provider has provided me with a Private_key.pem file, and then I should use it to decrypt the encrypted data they provided.

They have provided a demo coding in Ruby to help me do this. It works well in Ruby, but when I want to make it in Java, I find that there is a lot of difficulties.

The demo in Ruby:

```rb
def decrypt(key, encrypted_data)
  # Decode the Base64 encoded `encrypted_message` and `tag`
  ciphertext = Base64.strict_decode64(encrypted_data[:encrypted_message])
  mac = Base64.strict_decode64(encrypted_data[:tag])

  # Compute shared secret using the private key of the certificate and `ephemeral_public_key`
  ephemeral_public_key_pem = encrypted_data[:ephemeral_public_key]
  ephemeral_public_key = OpenSSL::PKey::EC.new(ephemeral_public_key_pem).public_key
  shared_secret = key.dh_compute_key(ephemeral_public_key)

  # Compute the hmac of decoded `encrypted_message` and ensure it matches the decoded value of `tag`
  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('AES-256-CTR')
  mac_digest = OpenSSL::Digest.new('SHA256')
  mac_length = mac_digest.digest_length / 2
  key_pair = OpenSSL::KDF.hkdf(
    shared_secret,
    length: cipher.key_len + mac_length,
    hash: 'SHA256',
    salt: '',
    info: ''
  )
  cipher_key = key_pair.byteslice(0, cipher.key_len)
  hmac_key = key_pair.byteslice(-mac_length, mac_length)
  computed_mac = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(mac_digest, hmac_key, ciphertext).byteslice(0, mac_length)
  raise OpenSSL::PKey::ECError, "Invalid Message Authenticaton Code" unless OpenSSL.secure_compare(computed_mac, mac)

  # Decrypt `encrypted_message`
  cipher.decrypt
  cipher.iv = ("\x00" * 16).force_encoding(Encoding::BINARY)
  cipher.key = cipher_key
  cipher.update(ciphertext) + cipher.final
end

# the encrypted data to be decrypted
encrypted_data = {
  encrypted_message: "7oeGaIk3Tja5fkyB3P[...]urLyxgW4J9lu2x769+",
  ephemeral_public_key: "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMEB3wYo[...]HKFkwjQ==\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n",
  tag: "LDCZ1tbHX8t+KPO9w=="
}
# Use `fingerprint` to identify the certificate that's used for encryption
key = OpenSSL::PKey::EC.new(File.open('path/to/private-key.file').read)
# decrypt
decrypt(key, encrypted_data)
```

One of the difficulties is I can't read the private_key.pem properly. The code below:

```java
public static KeyFactory keyFactory;
    static {
        if (Security.getProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME) == null) {
            Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        }
        try {
            keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException e) {
        }
    }

    public static PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String filePath) throws Exception {
        String privateKeyPEM = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        String privateKeyPEMTrimmed = privateKeyPEM
                .replace("-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
                .replace("-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
                .replaceAll("\n", "");
        byte[] privateKeyBytes = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(privateKeyPEMTrimmed)
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8EncodedKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyBytes);
        return keyFactory.generatePrivate(pkcs8EncodedKeySpec);
    }
```

The private_key.pem file looks like:

```
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHADASDAS265546XCADAP8zAOJPkW7OXTqotoAoGCCqGSM49
AadADASDASDCLKJOI45646asdcasDASDASD122165165D4sdasdsadqDASFAGFAADy
Aufttttttttttttttttttttw==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

When I run this code, it returns an error:

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: encoded key spec not recognized: unknown object in getInstance: org.bouncycastle.asn1.DEROctetString
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.util.BaseKeyFactorySpi.engineGeneratePrivate(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.ec.KeyFactorySpi.engineGeneratePrivate(Unknown Source)
```

I have searched methods and one on them is changing the private_key.file to PKCS#8 format format in OpenSSL, I do so and it works without error in this code. However, the result is not equal to tag of the encrypted_data in the decrypt function.

The decrypt function is:

```
public static byte[] decrypt(Key key, ShopifyCreditCardMethodData encryptedPayload) throws Exception {
    // Decode the Base64 encoded `encrypted_message` and `tag`
    byte[] ciphertext = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedPayload.getEncrypted_message());
    byte[] mac = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedPayload.getTag());

    // Compute shared secret using the private key of the certificate and `ephemeral_public_key`
    String s = encryptedPayload.getEphemeral_public_key().replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "")
            .replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "")
            .replaceAll("\\n", "");
    byte[] ephemeralPublicKeyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(s);
    X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(ephemeralPublicKeyBytes);
    PublicKey ephemeralPublicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
    KeyAgreement keyAgreement = KeyAgreement.getInstance("ECDH", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
    keyAgreement.init((PrivateKey) key);
    keyAgreement.doPhase(ephemeralPublicKey, true);
    byte[] sharedSecret = keyAgreement.generateSecret();

    // Compute the hmac of decoded `encrypted_message` and ensure it matches the decoded value of `tag`
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
    MessageDigest macDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
    int macLength = macDigest.getDigestLength() / 2;
    byte[] keyPair = hkdf(sharedSecret, cipher.getBlockSize() + macLength, "HmacSHA256");
    byte[] cipherKey = Arrays.copyOfRange(keyPair, 0, cipher.getBlockSize());
    byte[] hmacKey = Arrays.copyOfRange(keyPair, keyPair.length - macLength, keyPair.length);
    Mac hmac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
    hmac.init(new SecretKeySpec(hmacKey, "HmacSHA256"));
    byte[] computedMac = Arrays.copyOf(hmac.doFinal(ciphertext), macLength);
    if (!MessageDigest.isEqual(computedMac, mac)) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid Message Authenticaton Code");
    }

    // Decrypt `encrypted_message`
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(cipherKey, "AES"), new IvParameterSpec(new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()]));
    return cipher.doFinal(ciphertext);
}

public static byte[] hkdf(byte[] ikm, int length, String hashAlgorithm, byte[] salt, byte[] info) throws Exception {
    Mac hmac = Mac.getInstance(hashAlgorithm);
    hmac.init(new SecretKeySpec(salt != null ? salt : new byte[hmac.getMacLength()], hashAlgorithm));
    byte[] prk = hmac.doFinal(ikm);

    byte[] t = new byte[0];
    byte[] okm = new byte[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.ceil((double) length / hmac.getMacLength()); i++) {
        hmac.init(new SecretKeySpec(prk, hashAlgorithm));
        hmac.update(t);
        hmac.update(info);
        hmac.update((byte) (i + 1));
        t = hmac.doFinal();

        System.arraycopy(t, 0, okm, i * hmac.getMacLength(), Math.min(hmac.getMacLength(), length - i * hmac.getMacLength()));
    }

    return okm;
}

public static byte[] hkdf(byte[] ikm, int length, String hashAlgorithm) throws Exception {
    return hkdf(ikm, length, hashAlgorithm, null, new byte[0]);
}
```

I am not familiar with the asymmetric encryption system, and I try me best, but I can't find questions in my Java code with the Ruby code.

Comment: I have sloved these issues. The omission in my code is due to the wrong use of Cipher. It seems that it use empty 32-byte array in OpenSsl while empty 16-byte array array in Bouncycastle library of Java. So it leads to subsequent array copying and cutting with the wrong length of cipher. Just replace the length of the cipher with 32 not 16, and then it works well.